# System time is shifted forward 2 hours everytime I change network

Tags: release-hera, time

On my Date & Time settings I have it set to Network Time which usually works fine, but every time I change the network (when I move between work and home) the time gets shifted 2 hours forward. It gets fixed by just flipping the switch for Network Time on and off.
I've tried leaving Network Time off and the same thing happens.

I'm not switching countries or timezone when I move, I'm always within Central European Time.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using dual boot. try this solution: [How to Fix Windows and Linux Showing Different Times When Dual Bootin](https://www.howtogeek.com/323390/how-to-fix-windows-and-linux-showing-different-times-when-dual-booting/)g